# when one std::vector object is in stack and the other one is in heap, is the time complexity of the swap function of vector is O(1) or O(n)?

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity, swap

in C++ reference website
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/
it says the complexity of swap function of std::vector is constant. I guess it may archive this by changing the reference to the content of vector, however, when one std::vector object is in stack and the other one is in heap，it can't archive this by changing the reference to the content of vector. so, is the complexity of the swap function of vector is always O(1), how the archive this when one std::vector object is in stack and the other one is in heap?

Answer (score 2):

The actual content of a vector is nearly always on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

That reference also says:

> Another vector container of the same type (i.e., instantiated with the
>   same template parameters, T and Alloc) whose content is swapped with
>   that of this container.

as you can see allocator for both vectors must be the same which means that actual data is allocated on the same place, by default on the heap.

If you look into cpprefence [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) (which is usually more accurate), it says:

> If
>   std::allocator_traits::propagate_on_container_swap::value
>   is true, then the allocators are exchanged using an unqualified call
>   to non-member swap. Otherwise, they are not swapped (and if
>   get_allocator() != other.get_allocator(), the behavior is undefined).

so you can even swap vectors with different allocators, if they are swapable. Anyway swap will be constant operation as data is not stored inside vector objects itself, but in memory created and managed by allocator.